# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, exception

I have a Web App that wasn't working, so I wrote a main method to see where the problem was:

The driver is in Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Classpath

And in Libraries -> Web App Libraries (in the Project explorer) and in WEB-INF -> lib

The jar is mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.

I already tried to add this to my connection String:

```
useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

But it didn't work.

I tried to connect with the MySql command line to test that the db is actually working, and that succeeded, so I know that's not the issue.

I'm getting errors for the following code:

```
public synchronized static void aggiungiCliente() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String insertSQL = "insert into utente values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    try {
        connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "aa");  
        preparedStatement.setString(2,"aa");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "aa"); 
        preparedStatement.setString(4, "aa"); 
        preparedStatement.setString(5,"aa"); 
        preparedStatement.setString(6, "aa");
        preparedStatement.setInt(7, 12);
        preparedStatement.setString(8,"aa"); 
        preparedStatement.setString(9, "aa"); 
        preparedStatement.setString(10,"aa");
        preparedStatement.setInt(11, 12); 
        preparedStatement.setInt(12, 12);
        preparedStatement.setDate(13, java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now())); 
        preparedStatement.setString(14,"aa"); 
        preparedStatement.setString(15,"aa"); 
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (preparedStatement != null)
                preparedStatement.close();
        } finally {
            ConnectionPool.releaseConnection(connection);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        aggiungiCliente();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
}
```

**That's the Connection Pool app**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.LinkedList; 
import java.util.List;

public class ConnectionPool {

static {
    freeDbConnections = new LinkedList<Connection>();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("DB driver not found:"+ e.getMessage());
    } 
}

private static synchronized Connection createDBConnection() throws SQLException {

    Connection newConnection = null;
    
    String ip = "localhost";
    String port = "3306";
    String db = "code_omnia?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "Bonucci97";
    
    
    newConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ ip+":"+ port+"/"+db, username, password);
    newConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
    return newConnection;
}

public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection;

    if (!freeDbConnections.isEmpty()) {
        connection = (Connection) freeDbConnections.get(0);
        freeDbConnections.remove(0);

        try {
            if (connection.isClosed())
                connection = getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            connection.close();
            connection = getConnection();
        }
    } else {
        connection = createDBConnection();
    }

    return connection;
}

public static synchronized void releaseConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null)
        freeDbConnections.add(connection);
}





private static List<Connection> freeDbConnections;
}
```

**And the Stack Trace**

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:902)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
> at model.ConnectionPool.createDBConnection(ConnectionPool.java:28)
> at model.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:49)
> at model.Query.aggiungiCliente(Query.java:38)
> at model.Query.main(Query.java:20)
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'ora legale Europa occidentale' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
> at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:128)
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2236)
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2260)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1314)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:865)
> ... 10 more

Comment: The stack trace clearly says the reason: `Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'ora legale Europa occidentale' is unrecognized...`. There's a configuration problem.